# What's the best way to use OpenDJ (was OpenDS) as the data store for OpenAM (was OpenSSO)?

Tags: opensso

I've found a few how-tos, but they're based on old versions of both libraries (and contain references for files that seem to have been removed from OpenAM/OpenSSO) - for example:

http://blogs.oracle.com/indira/entry/using_opends_as_user_store

I've tried importing the old version of am_remote_opends_schema.ldif, but I get a fairly verbose error:

```
ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21)
 additional info: An error occurred while attempting to decode the object class "( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.2.181 NAME 'iplanet-am-managed-filtered-group' DESC 'Managed Filter Group OC' SUP iplanet-am-managed-group X-ORIGIN 'OpenSSO' )":  The definition for objectclass 2.16.840.1.113730.3.2.181 is invalid because it has an objectclass type of STRUCTURAL but this is incompatible with the objectclass type AUXILIARY for the superior class iplanet-am-managed-group
```

Should I roll back to the versions of OpenAM and OpenDJ to the older versions of OpenSSO and OpenDS referenced in these how-tos? That seems like a not-so-pleasing approach, but if it would do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

Michael,

OpenAM delivers the necessary files for OpenDJ (or OpenDS) but you can find them as well in OpenAM source repository : http://sources.forgerock.org/browse/openam/trunk/opensso/products/amserver/war/ldif/opends

The documentation from OpenSSO still applies to OpenAM, just s/opensso/openam/ likewise between OpenDJ and OpenDS. Doc: http://wikis.sun.com/display/OpenSSO/Using+OpenDS+as+a+User+Data+Store+for+OpenSSO+Enterprise+8.0+Update+1

I hope this helps.
Ludo

Comment: thanks again for the help! I figured they must be somewhere, but I wasn't sure where to look. I'll give it a shot!